# Deleting background color from one word in a highlighted sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can highlight text by creating a span but when I go to create a span in that highlighted span text with background color transparent, it inherits the parent tag background color still instead of adopting a background color of transparent.
The text will, however, adopt any color that is not transparent.
I'm basing my highlighting of text off of: http://help.dottoro.com/ljcvtcaw.php
and more specifically http://help.dottoro.com/external/examples/ljcvtcaw/execCommand_4.htm.

I've also used document.execCommand('ForeColor', false, yellow) in the past which was really intuitive and would delete or combine span tags but was never able to delete the span tags created in that way.

```
function Highlight(color) {
    document.designMode = "on";
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(editor.startContainer, editor.startOffset);
    range.setEnd(editor.endContainer, editor.endOffset);
    sel.addRange(range);
    if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
      var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      var startContainer = range.startContainer;
      var startOffset = range.startOffset;
      var endContainer = range.endContainer;
      var endOffset = range.endOffset;

  if(startContainer == endContainer){
    ColorizeNodeFromTo(startContainer, color, startOffset, endOffset);
  }
  else {
    if(startContainer.firstChild){
      var startLeaf = startContainer.childNodes[startOffset];
    }
    else {
      var startLeaf = GetNextLeaf(startContainer);
      ColorizeLeafFromTo(startContainer, color, startOffset, -1);
    }
    if(endContainer.firstChild){
      if(endOffset > 0){
        var endLeaf = endContainer.childNodes[endOffset-1];
      }
      else{
        var endLeaf = GetPreviousLeaf(endContainer);
      }
    }
    else{
      var endLeaf = GetPreviousLeaf(endContainer);
      ColorizeLeafFromTo(endContainer, color, 0, endOffset);
    }
    while(startLeaf){
      var nextLeaf = GetNextLeaf(startLeaf);
      ColorizeLeaf(startLeaf, color);
      if(startLeaf == endLeaf){
        break;
      }
      startLeaf = nextLeaf;
    }
  }
}
```

**Solution**

I've gone back and refactored my code using the execCommand function.

```
if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
   if (!document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, color)) {
     document.execCommand("BackColor", false, color);
   }
}
```

This dynamically creates and deletes spans how I want.

Comment: Please add specific code snippets that illustrate the solutions you have attempted. Your html, css, etc.. It's difficult to help without seeing what hasn't worked.

Comment: Dumping your entire code on here for others to try and sift through is going to severely limit the number of answers you get. Please edit your question by showing only the relevant areas of code.